# Vertical line within bars of a stacked bar chart using recharts or highcharts

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, recharts

How do I add a line like the one in first bar. It will be on percentage basis i.e. full width of the bar is 100%. Any clue will be helpful. My current chart is based on [the code from this simple example](http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/StackedBarChart)
I'm OK to switch to highcharts if it works with that.

[image: Desired Chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily draw those line by using the Highcharts library.

To do it you will need to define those line as a new series, where you will need to define x and y values to fit the line on the chart.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v3gmph9w/

```
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
}, {
        type: 'line',
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    data: [{x:0, y: 3}, {x: 0, y: 5}]
}]
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data

Comment: Thanks. The line is always in the middle of the bar. Can it be according to percentage value?

Comment: You can set decimal values to manipulate the line position. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8ear09gq/

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Basically -0.25 to +0.25 from the index is 0% to 100%